# Как выполнить длительную задачу на андроид 12+?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

По [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running) `WorkManager` может запускать задачи, которые долго выполняются (больше 10 минут). Для этого нужно вызвать `setForeground()`. Но в тоже время, версии андроид 12+ не дают запускать `foreground`, когда задача запускается по расписанию из `background` без активного приложения на переднем плане. `Service` в `background` убивают чуть ли не сразу после запуска.

Еще есть способы выполнить длительную задачу в фоне на старших андроидах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Foreground service launch restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#foreground-service-launch-restrictions)

> Consider using WorkManager to schedule and start expedited work while
> your app runs in the background. To complete time-sensitive actions
> that the user requests, start foreground services within an exact
> alarm.

Предлагается создавать `exact alarm` и при его срабатывании запускать foreground service/workmanager.
`exact alarm` одно из исключений, позволяющее запускать foreground из background: [Exemptions from background start restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restriction-exemptions)

> Your app invokes an exact alarm to complete an action that the user requests.

Но для `exact alarm` требуется `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>`
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact